# How to plot a list, which its elements are either None or elements that contain square bracket (list in list) in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list which looks like the following:

```
a = [None, None, None, None, None, [0.0016], [0.0015], [0.0014], [0.0014], [0.0013], None, None, None]
```

The problem is when I want to plot this list it returns an error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(a)
```

*ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.*

What I actually want, is that those None values are ignored and appears like empty spaces.

As an example using sin function as an array, my desired output with empty spaces would be something like:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeX0a.png)

Comment: @PatrickArtner I get this error:
  File "<string>", line 1
    b = [[] if elem is None else for elem in b]
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: try plotting `[[] if elem is None else elem for elem in a]` - sorry for the typo

Comment: This returns the same error as the first error: _ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence_.
But thank you, I found another solution to this based on your answer:
`b = [None if elem is None else elem[0] for elem in a]`
it works, however I don't know if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: You can provide x and y data to plot using gaps, see https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/nan_test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to transform the items, which you can do using a short function and list comprehension. To ensure the `None` values are plotted, you also need to set the `xlim` of the plot so that the x-axis goes from 0 to the length of the list. (You are implicitly plotting values on the y-axis against list indices on the x-axis.)

```
def transform(item):
    if item is None:
        return None
    else:
        return item[0]

a = [transform(item) for item in a]
plt.xlim(0, len(a))
plt.plot(a)
```

Comment: Would  `a = [None if item is None else item[0] for item in a]` be a good alternative?

Comment: @JohanC yes it would

Answer (score 0):

You can change each None for 0 in the following way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [None, None, None, None, None, [0.0016], [0.0015], [0.0014], [0.0014], [0.0013], None, None, None]

plt.plot([x[0] if not x is None else 0 for x in a])
plt.show()
```